# How can I convert my list of lists to fixed size matrix?

Tags: list, matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I want to create Hemming Matrix. I have just built Galois field like multiplicative group. That's what I got:

```
MultiplicativeGroup = DeleteDuplicates[
   NestList[
    PolynomialMod[
      PolynomialMod[(generating*#), irreducablePolynomial], 2] &, 1, 
    n]];
```

{1, a, a^2, 1 + a^2, 1 + a + a^2, 1 + a, a + a^2}

After that I converted it into binary form which look like this one:

```
CoefficientList[MultiplicativeGroup, a]
```

{{1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}
But I stuck with converting it into binary matrix form. It's have to look like this one:

```
(0  0   1   1   1   0   1
0   1   0   0   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   1   1   0)
```

But I actually don't know how to do it. I can't transpose it or do anything else. Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array = {{1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}

PadLeft[#, 3] & /@ Reverse[array, 2] // Transpose
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

I did it in this way:

```
generating = a^Mod[(2^m - 1)/n, m];

MultiplicativeGroup = DeleteDuplicates@
   NestList[
    PolynomialMod[
      PolynomialMod[(generating*#), irreducablePolynomial], 2] &, 1, 
    n];

Print[MatrixForm[Reverse[Transpose[CoefficientList[MG, a, m]]]]];
```